# Memory usage of an array of arrays referencing a single array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, space-complexity

Suppose in Python3 I have an array of size N and an array of N arrays.

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(N):
  a.append(i)

for i in range(N):
  b.append(a)
```

Each b[i] now references the same array **a**. I think that this is still O(N) memory because when I access an array I am really accessing a reference to a block of memory so each b[i] holds constant space memory (the address to a) and the array **a** holds O(N) memory, so altogether this should be O(N) memory, rather than O(N^2) if each of the N^2 cells in b holds an independent value. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm honestly having a hard time following you. Talking about "blocks of memory" in Python is rarely useful. There are strange aspects of your code, e.g. `b = [[] for i in range(N)]` that don't really add anything but just distract. In any case, it *sounds* like you have the right idea, Python **lists** (these are not arrays) and all containers hold references to Python objects. IOW, when you do `b[i] = a` you are **not creating a copy of `a`**

Comment: Could you explain why talking about "blocks of memory" in Python is rarely useful? I don't really understand how Python behaves under the hood with memory usage. I'm sort of assuming that it behaves somewhat like C where an array for instance has a physical chunk of memory for each element of the array.
Also you're right, I could just create b as an empty array and append a N times.

Comment: Please do not assume that a Python list is anything but remotely similar to a C array, either in behaviour or memory allocation.

Comment: In terms of memory allocation, it's actually very much like a C array, since it's literally an (overallocated) array of references. That's why `insert` is an O(n) operation, and `append` is only O(1) *amortized*. The language makes no reference to how memory is handled, but it does promise runtime behavior that only makes sense if the implementation uses an array.

Comment: A Python list does not consume memory, for the simple reason that it is no more than an abstract definition of a type in the language. If you want to discuss the runtime behaviour of it you have to name the implemention you want to discuss about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's O(N) for all practical purposes. `a` contains `N` references to `int` objects, and `b` contains `N` references to `a`. That's `2N` references.

---

Technically, the amount of memory used by each `int` object referenced by `a` is a function of `N`, but because it's something like 24 + `O(log_{2**32} N)` bytes per `int` object, the hidden constant is so small that it only makes a difference when `N` is astronomically large (larger than any amount of memory you are likely able to afford or address).

On the other hand, the length of a list is also capped at `sys.maxlen` elements, which means in some sense that all lists use O(1) memory (with a very large constant). :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the interesting points! Very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. `a`'s size is O(n), and `b` holds N references **to the same instance of `a`**. Overall, the memory complexity is O(n).